# KeyStoreException: This keystore does not support probing and must be loaded with a specified type

Tags: java, linux, certificate, keytool

I'm getting this error while trying to add .crt certificate to already existing keystore via terminal. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Java 11

I tried to run this command:

```
$ keytool -import -alias ca -file my_certificate_file_name.crt -keystore my_truststore_file_name
```

And also tried to run without alias:

```
$ keytool -import -file my_certificate_file_name.crt -keystore my_truststore_file_name
```

Comment: How was the keystore file created originally?

Comment: @user207421 I have no idea, this file was created by another developer who does not work anymore

Comment: Please show the relevant code and data, and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Android uses another type of truststore named "BKS". Commands in question were related to "JKS" type of truststore.

```
$ keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "your_cert_file" -alias ca -keystore "your_truststore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "path_to_bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass your_password
```

Besides, it is required to download "bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" file.
You can do it from maven repo: **https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46**

After executing the command above in terminal, "BKS" truststore was successfully created.